# Enum as parameter: Get name and index

Tags: c#

I have an enum like this:

```
public enum Global
{
  txt_test = 123
}
```

Now I want to use a call like this:

```
var text = lib.Get(Global.txt_test);
```

Method:

```
public TextString Get(Enum enumeration)
{
  string name = enumeration.ToString();
  int index = ?;  // (int)enumeration not working      
  ...
}
```

How to get the index of an enum in this case? 
Or am I doing it wrong at all?

Thank you.

Solution:

```
public TextString Get(Enum enumeration)
{
   string name = enumeration.ToString();
   int index = Convert.ToInt32(enumeration);    
   ...
}
```

Comment: What do you even mean by "index"? What value would you expect and why?

Comment: In this case I mean 123

Comment: What is the `TextString` type?

Comment: That is just my enum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sbbt4032.aspx) are convertible to `int` for retrieving their values:

```
public TextString Get(Enum enumeration)
{
  string name = enumeration.ToString();
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(enumeration);

  // ...
  return null;
}
```

Note that this will work because your enumeration is type of int by default. Enums can still be other value type like long :

```
enum Range : long { Max = 2147483648L, Min = 255L };
```

In this case, the conversion will lost precision.

Comment: Cannot convert type System.Enum to int

Comment: @K.D. : I updated my anwswer. The cast couldn't work because you act on the base class of Enums. Convert.ToInt32 will work.

Comment: Change Enum to Global

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the enum value (what you are calling "index") as a string, the best way is to use custom format strings as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3s1ez6e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For example:

```
public TextString Get(Enum enumeration)
{
  string index = enumeration.ToString("D");

  // ...
  return null;
}
```